# Notepad++ search combination in lines

Tags: regex, search, notepad++

I am looking for a specific combination in a txt file that contains multiple lines (Notepad ++). The structure of a line I am looking for is as follows:

```
xxxxxx  N  N  -1  -1  -1  N (end line)
```

So I first have an identifier of 6 or more characters, followed by 6 numbers (N) spaced by a tab. N can be values 1, 0 or -1.
I am looking for those lines that contain '-1' in position 3, 4 and 5. The other positions can take any of the 3 values.
I have searched online and applied searches such as:

```
\t-?\t-?\t-1\t-1\t-1\t-?

\t?.\t?.\t-1\t-1\t-1\t?.

t?.\t?.\t-1\t-1\t-1\t?.\n

\t-1\t-1\t-1\t?.\n
```

Yet, the last N in the line is not taken into account, so that if its value is 0 for example, that line will not be selected.

What is the way to write this search? I understand Notepad ++ is written in C++.

Comment: Do you have access to a *nix platform or it's tools?

Comment: I use Notepad++ 'search/find'. Which platform or tools are you referring to? If another tool helps in finding that combination, I'd like to use it.

Comment: *nix refers to UNIX or Linux platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to follow this pattern?:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]{6,})\s*(-1|0|1)\s*(-1|0|1)\s*((-1\s*?){3})\s*(-1|0|1)\s?
```

https://regex101.com/r/yM5xD3/2

---

Explanation:

`^`: Start of the line.

`([a-zA-Z0-9]{6,})`: Any character six or more times.

`\s*`: space/tab/newLine zero o more times.

`(-1|0|1)`: One of those numbers.

`\s*`: ...

`(-1|0|1)`: One of those numbers.

`((-1\s*?){3})`: -1 one time followed by space/tab/newLine zero or more times. (The '?' means that the regex will try to get the less amount of \s as possible)

`\s*`: ..

`(-1|0|1)`: ...

And the last `\s?`: looks for zero or one Space/tab/newLineCharacter

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\t(-1|0|1)\t(-1|0|1)\t[\-][1]\t[\-][1]\t[\-][1]\t(-1|0|1)$
```

I tried on the following sample and it worked for me.

```
  xxxxxx    1   1   -1  -1  -1  1
  xxxxxx    0   1   -1  -1  -1  0
  test12    -1  1   -1  1   -1  0
  xxxxxx    1   1   -1  -1  -1  0
  test13    0   1   -1  -1  1   -1
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: your solution did not make any selection. I believe you take N as a letter value instead of -1, 0 or 1.

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood the issue. I have updated the regex. It should work now. (it expects no trailing spaces)